# Bootstrap 3.0.3 form-group class it is not taking any margin-bottom

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3.0.3 in this new project and there is something weird, the `form-group` class it is not taking any `margin-bottom`. The [**purpose of this class**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms) is to make vertical space between `labels` and `controls`. If I increase the margin-bottom to a number higher than 15px, it looks like the margin is been add up at the top. Any idea what's going on? This is my **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/labanino/fM2UW/2/embedded/result/)**. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to accomplish correctly, you should add the class `.form-horizontal` to your `form`, as seen in the 'Horizontal Form' section here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal